# Django: using mptt-django to allocate products to categories in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, django-mptt

I have a many-to-many relationship between products and categories. I am using mptt to manage the display of categories on the admin (which works fine) and so I can allocate products to categories.

While the categories are working fine, it's the product side I'm having problems with.

In my models.py I have (truncated for brevity):

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel,TreeForeignKey,TreeManyToManyField

class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

class Product(models.Model)
    categories = TreeManyToManyField(ProductCategory)
```

In my admin.py I have

```
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple
from .models import Product,ProductCategory
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin
from mptt.models import TreeManyToManyField

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   formfield_overrides = {
      TreeManyToManyField:{'widget':CheckboxSelectMultiple},
   }
```

This almost gets the job done but all of the categories are displayed with checkboxes which is not what I want since you don't want to add products to categories which have sub categories.

[image]

What I want is the display of categories such that you can only add products to categories which don't have children, so in this example

```
Category 1
Category 2 sub sub 
Category 3 sub
```

And the labels would be

```
Category 1
Category 2 > Catgory 2 sub > Category 2 sub sub
Category 3 > Category 3 sub
```

Many thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

Hi, I realise me question may be too broad!

As a Django newbie, what I think I need to do is create a custom widget possibly overriding the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget, that I can apply to my 'categories' model attribute.

At the moment, I am using formfield_overrides for the TreeManyToManyField as discussed above

```
formfield_overrides = {
    TreeManyToManyField:{'widget':CheckboxSelectMultiple},
}
```

Not only does this not give the desired result but also rather than using the standard CheckboxSelectMultiple for all TreeManyToMany fields, can I specify this widget just for my 'categories' attribute?

Notwithstanding this aside, would it be possible to show me how I can create a custom widget, passing the information about the category tree and selected states (for a product which has already been allocated to categories)? I've been trying to sort this myself but have been struggling - any help much appreciated!

**UPDATE FOLLOWING KARANTSTHR COMMENT**

Here is a screenshot of the categories - all good in showing the categories with no children, but can we show the parents to these categories in the label as described above?

[image]

**UPDATE 2 TO KARANTSTHR**

Here is a screenshot with your implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ModelAdmin is very flexible, you can specify custom ModelForm for **form** option in ProductAdmin (form is  ModelAdmin option ) to filter out categories not having any child category.
So,
I think you don't need custom widget to solve your problem, just change **admin.py** as

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple
from .models import Product,ProductCategory
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin
from mptt.models import TreeManyToManyField


class filterCategories(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(filterCategories, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['categories'].queryset = ProductCategory.objects.filter(children=None)


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = filterCategories
    formfield_overrides = { TreeManyToManyField:{'widget':CheckboxSelectMultiple},}


admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
admin.site.register(ProductCategory,MPTTModelAdmin)
```

**UPDATE 1** 
you need to add related_name in parent field of ProductCategory class in **models.py** 
So ProductCategory class in models.py would be as below

```
class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**UPDATE 2**
you can change **str** method for ProductCategory as follow for labels

```
def __str__(self):
    try:
        ancestors = self.get_ancestors(include_self=True)
        ancestors = [i.name for i in ancestors]
    except:
        ancestors = [self.name]

    return ' > '.join(ancestors[:len(ancestors) + 1])
```

note that this is not a radical approach for gaining label ( object's name ) of your choice, I will update my answer if I find a better solution.

Comment: HI, many thanks - almost there, please see my update above where I have posted an image. Although only the categories with no children are displaying (correctly), is it possible to show their parents in the label?